# Why strlen() can get the length of string and sizeof cannot in C?

Tags: c

I want to calculate the length of a string in C in VS Ccode, but when I use sizeof function, the time of compiling didn't stop and get any result; on the other hand, I can get the length by strlen function: why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    char greeting[] = "hello";

    int len = strlen(greeting);
    //int len = sizeof(greeting);       
    printf("length is:%d",len);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the difference between them: `strlen()` is used to get the length of an array of chars/string, while
`sizeof()` is used to get the actual size of any type of data in bytes. However, I don't know why there is no answer when I run sizeof.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no answer when I run sizeof"? It must return a number. Please make an [mre] of your attempt to use sizeof.

Comment: @HansPassant `char greeting[] = "hello";` is perfectly valid and should result in `sizeof greeting == 6` (5 plus 1 for the terminating `'\0'`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've invoked undefined behaviour: you're printing a value of type `size_t` with the format for an `int`.  This is not guaranteed to work.  Cast the value:

```
printf("length is: %d\n, (int)sizeof(greeting));
```

The result will be one larger than the result from `strlen()` because `strlen()` does not count the terminating null byte and `sizeof()` does.

Comment: The original code never tried to print a size_t with %d though?

Comment: @M.M — when I last looked, the post was deleted.  I misread the original code; this answer isn't dreadfully relevant — though the replacement code shows an added cast when passing the result of `sizeof()` as an argument to `printf()`.  OTOH, `strlen()` also returns `size_t`.  I was part way through adding a `%zu` alternative when things were deleted.  Chaos reigns.